# Using Caffeine for values on disk

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

I'm thinking about using [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) for values off-loaded to disk. The keys are small, but the values may take a few megabytes. I guess, I can rely on a `RemovalListener` for cleaning up the mess.

For limiting the disk usage, I can use `Caffeine.weigher`. However, `maximumWeight` can not be used together with `maximumSize`, so it may happen that I run out of memory (because of using many cache entries) before my disk fills enough to cause eviction.

I guess, it's improbable, but possible, as there's no lower bound on the average entry size.

- Does such a use of an in-memory cache make sense?
- Is there a good reason why `maximumSize` and `maximumWeight` are mutually exclusive? I can imagine that both share a single slot, but saving eight bytes per cache IMHO doesn't count.
- Is there a trick to circumvent this restriction?

Comment: `maximumSize` is effectively `maximumWeight` where every entry has a weight of 1. You would set a maximum, weigh by the byte size, and and keep the metadata in memory. What would your desired behavior be?

Comment: @BenManes I want two independent constraints: Limit the metadata by saying that only 1e6 entries are allowed and limit the disk space by saying that only 1e11 bytes may be used. I can get the former using `maximumSize` and the latter using `maximumWeight`, but not both.

Comment: If you averaged the lower bound to 1e5 it would never exceed the entry count, but could hit the byte count sooner. There probably isn’t a great solution to coerce this.

Comment: @BenManes Right. I can cheat by using `Math.max(100_000, size)` or even `100_000 + size` as the weight. At the moment, I don't have any real data about the cache usage as I'm just starting, but I guess, I'll get away with the cheat.